# Use inception v3 with batch of images in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, classification, batch-processing

In one of my project of computer vision, I use public pre-trained inception-v3 available here: http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz. This network is at the beginning of my classification chain (a lot of stuff is performed on logits produced by the network). I would like to feed this network with a batch of images (instead of sequentially processing images) in order to make it faster.
However, the provided network had been "frozen", and it can only process one image at a time.

Is there any solution to "unfreeze" a graph and adapt it so that I can use it on batch of images?

(*N.B* : I found related topics on the internet, but they all suggest to take a more recent network available for instance here :
http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-v3-2016-03-01.tar.gz. This is not what I would like to do since a lot of stuff has been tuned on the output of the frozen model.)

Comment: I managed to find a solution (by comparing at all operators in both graphs) and reconstruct a graph with appropriate weights. 
If someone encounters similar issue, I can share my code (or simply my modified frozen inception model).

Comment: I have the same problem and I was wondering if you could elaborate on how you solved it or share your code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is too late, but here is the code snippet that I used:

```
# First loan model into and old graph 
proto_file = ...  # downloaded inception protofile 
graph_def = tf.GraphDef.FromString(open(proto_file, 'rb').read())
to_delete = {“DecodeJpeg", "Cast", "ExpandDims", "pool_3/_reshape", "softmax"}
graph_def = delete_ops_from_graph(graph_def, to_delete)

new_graph = tf.Graph()
with new_graph.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, [None, None, None, 3], name="batched_inputs")
    x_cast = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.float32)
    y = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map={"ExpandDims:0": x_cast}, return_elements=["pool_3:0"],name="")

...
```

Now `new_graph` is the graph that has batch dimension (takes in 4d tensor NHWC). Note that this is good if you want to use inception-2015-12-05.tgz as a feature extractor. You would need to take the output from `output = new_graph.get_tensor_by_name("pool_3:0")`

For the definition of delete_ops_from_graph, see [Tensorflow: delete nodes from graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324534/tensorflow-delete-nodes-from-graph)