# remove nodes from a tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, nodes

This is my tensorflow 1.x graph and I want to remove the input nodes and map part and  feed my input to resnet part. to be more specific, I want to delete the decode part of the graph which decodes the input images.  How should I do it ? please  mention that by which format I should do it ? should I use frozen graph.pb or saved_model.pb or .ckpt files?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

finally, with the help of [This link](https://%5B1%5D:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324534/tensorflow-delete-nodes-from-graph) I successfully could remove some specific nodes with specific prefix in their names from the beginning of the graph.